# How to move text from under a rectangle to above it in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Basically I have a button (Rect) made which I tried to add text over it so that the button can be used as a start button. But when I move my text and set it to be over the button, the text goes below the button instead of appearing over it. This is my current code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Blackjack")
icon = pygame.image.load('jack.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
over_font = pygame.font.Font('GOODDP__.TTF', 64)
jack = pygame.image.load('rsz_jack.png')
jackX = 295
jackY = 100
running = True

def jack_title():
    screen.blit(jack, (jackX, jackY))

def display_title_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("Blackjack", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (292, 300))

def start_button():
    button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 255, 0], button)
    button.move(0, 0)
    over_text = over_font.render("START!", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (0, 75))
    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if clicked[0] == 1:
        print('Clicked left button!')
    elif clicked[1] == 1:
        print('Clicked middle button!')
    elif clicked[-1] == 1:
        print('Clicked right button!')
    else:
        pass


def quit_button():
    button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0 ,0], button)

def display_gameover_message():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (292, 300))

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((150, 173, 252))
    jack_title()
    display_title_text()
    start_button()
    quit_button()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text "START!" is covered by the red rectangle of the button which is draw in `quit_button`. Draw `start_button()` after `quit_button()`:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((150, 173, 252))
    jack_title()

    quit_button()
    start_button()
```

---

Anyway, I recommend to draw the buttons at different positions and to center the text to the button. e.g:

```py
start_button_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
quit_button_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 200, 100, 50)

def start_button():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 255, 0], start_button_rect)
    start_button_rect.move(0, 0)

    over_text = over_font.render("START!", True, (0, 0, 0))
    over_text_rect = over_text.get_rect(center = start_button_rect.center)
    screen.blit(over_text, over_text_rect)

    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if clicked[0] == 1:
        print('Clicked left button!')
    elif clicked[1] == 1:
        print('Clicked middle button!')
    elif clicked[-1] == 1:
        print('Clicked right button!')
    else:
        pass

def quit_button():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0 ,0], quit_button_rect)
```

Comment: omg! you fixed the main issue I had because I thought for a second those were the rectangle sizes, but its good to know they are actually the POSITION of the rectangle! Ty!!